# Understanding cats-effect forceR definition?

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-cats, cats-effect

```scala
def forceR[B](that: IO[B]): IO[B] =
    // cast is needed here to trick the compiler into avoiding the IO[Any]
    asInstanceOf[IO[Unit]].handleError(_ => ()).productR(that)
```

*[Source](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/series/3.x/core/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/IO.scala#L413)*

- Self `asInstanceOf[IO[Unit]]` turns self into a `IO[Unit]`
- and then `handleError` has the type `def handleError[B >: A](f: Throwable => B): IO[B]` which normally stats the type bound of returning `IO[B]` should be super type of `IO[Unit]`

Then why this `forceR` definition on the call site have the true `IO[B]` type such as `IO[Int]`?

Comment: Because `productR`? Or I'm not understanding your question and please reformulate.

Comment: No, not because of productR. There is a comment line above says "...avoiding the IO[Any]"

Comment: As explained very clearly by @Dmytro below, the comment apply to the part before `productR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is slightly confusing.

> Then why this `forceR` definition on the call site have the true `IO[B]` type such as `IO[Int]`?

Because the returned type of `forceR` is specified to be `IO[B]`. So it can't be anything else at the call site (if the code compiles).

I guess you mis-interprete the comment

```
// cast is needed here to trick the compiler into avoiding the IO[Any]
```

This is not to avoid return type `IO[Any]`. The return type will anyway be `IO[B]` because of `productR`, [@GaëlJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j) is correct

```
sealed abstract class IO[+A] ... {
  ...

  def productR[B](that: IO[B]): IO[B] =
    flatMap(_ => that)
```

So this is not intended to make `this.handleError(_ => ()).productR(that)` not `IO[Any]`, this seems to be intended to make `this.handleError(_ => ())` not `IO[Any]`.

If `this` is `IO[A]` and `A <: AnyVal` then `this.handleError(_ => ())` has type `IO[AnyVal]`. If not `A <: AnyVal` then `this.handleError(_ => ())` has type `IO[Any]`. Not sure why it's important in `handleError` though. Some reflection (`.getClass`), caching, stack tracing is used in `handleError`. Maybe error message is undesired for `IO[Any]`.

```
def handleError[B >: A](f: Throwable => B): IO[B] =
  handleErrorWith[B](t => IO.pure(f(t)))

def handleErrorWith[B >: A](f: Throwable => IO[B]): IO[B] =
  IO.HandleErrorWith(this, f, Tracing.calculateTracingEvent(f))

def calculateTracingEvent(key: Any): TracingEvent = {
  if (isCachedStackTracing) {
    val cls = key.getClass
    get(cls)
  } else if (isFullStackTracing) {
    buildEvent()
  } else {
    null
  }
}

/**
 * Holds platform-specific flags that control tracing behavior.
 *
 * <p>The Scala compiler inserts a volatile bitmap access for module field accesses. Because the
 * `tracingMode` flag is read in various IO constructors, we are opting to define it in a Java
 * source file to avoid the volatile access.
 *
 * <p>INTERNAL API with no source or binary compatibility guarantees.
 */
public final class TracingConstants {...}
```

Otherwise maybe casting was just a precaution and is not actually necessary :)

The specific commit where [@DanielSpiewak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815/daniel-spiewak)
 added the casting was here

https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/commit/66d30c4ccdfdb8aca5f6632f5506dda192fc2f03#diff-2dec4bb5f2b890f966e62cfdfcc6d32746235e45b4a14113f56e38b49923132aL367-R368

---

The interesting question is **why** actually Daniel needed not `IO[Any]` in the part before `productR` and **whether** he actually needed that. I'm not 100% sure.

> [@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez):
>
> This is just speculation, but I am fairly sure is just to allow compilation in the presence of strict compiler flags. As you may know, there is a flag to make the compiler warn if it infers `Any`, and another flag that turns all compiler warning into errors; thus stopping compilation. Additionally, as you may also be aware the **sbt-tpolecat** plugin enable those warnings and I am pretty sure most **typelevel** project either use that plugin, or enable a similar set of flags by other means. So, that is why they needed to avoid the inferred `Any` while recovering from the possible errors.

Makes sense.

Comment: This answer is great. Just adding onto it quickly (rather than making a competing answer which wouldn't be as good), I *could* have written this as `void.handleErrorWith(_ => ()).productR(that)`, but replacing `asInstanceOf[IO[Unit]]` with `void` is much less efficient since it results in multiple allocations and additional runloop stages! The cast is invisible since we ignore the value, so it doesn't matter that `A` isn't `Unit`.

Comment: @DanielSpiewak Thanks for your comment. It's understandable that `asInstanceOf[IO[Unit]]` is more effective than `void`. The question is why `void` or `asInstanceOf[IO[Unit]]` is necessary, why `handleError(_ => ()).productR(that)` is not enough. It's understandable that `handleError(_ => ()).productR(that)` is `handleError[Any](_ => ()).productR[B](that)`. The question is why `[Any]` is bad. Is it because of compiler warnings as Luis assumed? Is it true that `Any` doesn't make impact on stack tracing in `handleError`? Thank you.